# Angular material tab group gray underline

Tags: angular-material, tabs

[v15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoVWP.png)
[v14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7zPn.png)
As you can see from the image, after angular v15, gray underline of tab group is disappeared.

Is there any way for getting the gray line back on v15? I investigated properties but it seems there is no way for getting it back.

Answer (score 0):

The new material design components don't include a divider anymore (because modernism). You can easily style it in with

```css
.mat-mdc-tab-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--mat-divider-color);
}
```

This snippet uses the official color variable for the divider. So if you would change/restyle the color of the divider, it would also affect the Tab-Header.